# Storing Functions as Values in Firebase

Tags: jquery, firebase

I'm looking for more guidance and help on storing functions as values in Firebase and using within an HTML document.

1. Is it feasible and possible to store functions as values in Firebase?
2. Assuming I can save a function as a value in Firebase, could someone please give me some direction and guidance on calling the Firebase value for the function and applying within a script?  Below is the function that works great within my script, but the function itself will be used exactly the same for 100's of docs and I'd like to make this piece turn-key in case I need to change syntax within the function later.

Below is the function I'm using:

```
function doThat()
{
   $.getJSON(practice_URL, 
   function(data){
      $.each(data.objects, function(i, obj){
         var li = $("<li></li>");
         var html = "<h1>"+obj.name+"</h1>";
         html += "<p>"+obj.description+"</p>";
         html += "<p>"+obj.venue.name+", "+
         obj.venue.street_address+", "+
         obj.venue.locality+", "+
         obj.venue.country+", "+
         obj.venue.postal_code+
         "</p><hr/>";
         li.html(html);
         $("#ul-data").append(li);
      });   
   });  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've stored function definitions in Firebase in the past, without any problems.

To retrieve them I used`eval`, but there are probably better ways to accomplish the same.

```js
handlersRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    eval('handlers["'+snapshot.name()+'"] = '+snapshot.val());
});
handlersRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
    eval('handlers["'+snapshot.name()+'"] = '+snapshot.val());
});
```

I then invoke the functions like this:

```js
function runTask(id) {
    var task = tasks.get(id);
    if (task) {
        var handler = handlers[task.type];
        handler.call(task, id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a string representation of the function with [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString).
2. Store the string on Firebase Database.
3. On retrieving the string, call [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) on it, to parse it and then use it as needed.

I assume these are functions that you pre-define - not editable by users (to avoid code injection). So make sure you disallow writing these function strings with [Firebase Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart).

#### Example

```js
// Create the function string
const fun = function(name) { console.log('Hello ' + name) };
const funString = fun.toString();

// Store it on RTDB
firebase.ref('/myFunctionStrings/helloWorld').set(funString);

// Retrieve it
firebase.ref('/myFunctionStrings/helloWorld').once('value', snapshot => {
  const funString = snapshot.val();
  const fun = eval("(" + funString + ")");

  // Call it!
  fun('Joe') // Output: Hello Joe
});
```